# Javascript Problem

Tags: javascript

I am trying to populate list boxes with data and at the same time display the number of users currently logged in.

I have the following code.

```
<body onload = "getNumberOfOnlineUsers();" onbeforeunload = "leaveChat();">
<body onload="initListGroup('links', document.forms[0].category, document.forms[0].site);">
```

The two chain boxes are rendered but the data is not populated.The number of current users too is displayed.

When i put,`<body onload="initListGroup('links', document.forms[0].category, document.forms[0].site);">`

above `<body onload = "getNumberOfOnlineUsers();" onbeforeunload = "leaveChat();">`

The chaine boxes are now working okay,but the number of users is not displayed.What could be the problem?.

Comment: Hm. Are you telling you have *two* body tags?

Comment: Do you really have 2 <body> tags ?  That's not really supported and does weird things depending on which browser you use.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know an HTML page could contain the BODY tag twice.

Comment: Yes,for the development,i have two,i am wondering how i can comment them into one.

Comment: From the looks of it you're trying to put TWO body tags in your html doc, which is not supported in the spec at all. Why do you have two body tags???

Comment: @Marco - an HTML page can contain any tag any number of times. It just may not be valid ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only have one `<body>` element in your page.  The second one is being ignored.
Instead, you could try this:

```
<body onload = "getNumberOfOnlineUsers(); initListGroup('links', document.forms[0].category, document.forms[0].site);" onbeforeunload = "leaveChat();">
```

Comment: You're welcome. Please consider marking one of the answers as the accepted answer. And it probably shouldn't be mine, as I was the fourth to post the correct answer in quick succession! @Jason Benson was first, but personally, I prefer @Tomalak's answer.

Comment: I am not that dumb,i explained earlier on that,i shouldn't have posted double body tags.

Answer (score 4):

if it's one page you should have only one body tag.

try

```
<body onload="getNumberOfOnlineUsers();initListGroup('links', document.forms[0].category, document.forms[0].site;">
```

Answer (score 0):

yo can't use two body tags.. do it like this:

```
<script>
  function init(){
    getNumberOfOnlineUsers();
    initListGroup('links', document.forms[0].category, document.forms[0].site);

  }
  function destruct(){
    leaveChat();
  }

</script>
<body onload='init();' onunload='destruct();'>
```